# How to parse chunk of CSV data with white space line breaks into list of data frames

Tags: r, tidyverse, readr

I have the following text file, it contains several chunk of table.
Each chunk is separated by white space.

```
GENERALIZED BORN:
Complex Energy Terms
Frame #,BOND,ANGLE
0,6603.0521,7264
1,7434.9885,7602

Receptor Energy Terms
Frame #,BOND,ANGLE
0,6140.6338,5383.1241
1,6885.2965,5653.6637

Ligand Energy Terms
Frame #,BOND,ANGLE
0,462.4183,1881.428
1,549.692,1949.0482
```

How can I use R to parse this single text file into list of three data frames, or tibbles?

I tried this but failed:

```
library(readr)
readr::read_lines_chunked("myfile.txt", skip =1, chunk_size = 4)
```

Because `readr::read_lines_chunked` can't recognized the white space separator between chunks.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me if that function was suppose to be used like that. My guess is not. But you can parse the data manually. Create a list, parse out chunks and save it into a list.

```r
xy <- readLines(con = "test.txt")
xy <- xy[-1]  # remove GENERALIZED BORN

xy <- xy[which(xy != "")]
# Start of a break is needed for names and subsetting in a loop.
breaks <- which(grepl("^.*Energy Terms", x = xy))

dfs <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(breaks))
names(dfs) <- xy[breaks]

# Adding one accounts for the Energy Terms line. It's either here
# or in the loop.
chunks <- breaks + 1

for (chunk in seq_along(chunks)) {
  # If we extract the name and use it to subset, the order of the
  # dfs doesn't really matter.
  chk.name <- xy[chunks[chunk] - 1]
  
  from <- chunks[chunk]
  to <- chunks[chunk + 1] - 2
  
  # When working with the last chunk, this sets the end of the text.
  if (is.na(to)) {
    to <- length(xy)
  }
  
  chk <- xy[from:to]

  tmp <- read.table(
    text =  paste(chk, collapse = "\n"), 
    header = TRUE, 
    comment.char = "", 
    sep = ","
    )
  
  dfs[[chk.name]] <- tmp
}
```

And the result

```
$`Complex Energy Terms`
  Frame..     BOND ANGLE
1       0 6603.052  7264
2       1 7434.989  7602

$`Receptor Energy Terms`
  Frame..     BOND    ANGLE
1       0 6140.634 5383.124
2       1 6885.297 5653.664

$`Ligand Energy Terms`
  Frame..     BOND    ANGLE
1       0 462.4183 1881.428
2       1 549.6920 1949.048
```